# Project migration from 32bit to 64bit not successful

Tags: c++, visual-studio, x86, 32bit-64bit, porting

I am working on a project that includes 15 projects in C++. This project was developed in 2010 for the 32bit architecture. Now, I want to port this project to 64bit.

First, I compiled it with a 32bit configuration in VS2019. The code compiles successfully, but the executables generated do not work. I assume this issue may be due to compatibility issues of 32bit architecture with 64bit architecture.

That's why I changed the configuration to 64bit. I added the path for 64bit libs in project properties, and replaced third party libs with 64bit versions. But when I compile the code, it fails and the error states:

> X files are not found

When I checked external dependencies, those files are not showing there, which were there in the 32bit configuration.

So, I checked the projects to which files belonged, and I found out for those projects, even though I changed their configuration, are still running in a 32bit configuration. When I change individual projects to 64bit and close the configuration manager, they change back.

Can anyone tell me the reason for this, and how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Add visual-studio tag to your question. You might get an answer sooner.

Comment: If the code does not work in 32-bits, the problem is most likeky due to the code itself.  MS compilers have a very bad record when it comes to upgrading to a new compiler version.   Get everuything to work in 32 bots first.

Comment: _I assume this issue may be due to compatibility issues of 32bit architecture with 64bit architecture._   Doesn't look like a good assumptions, I don't recall any issues specific to cross-compilation; also VS2019 has 32-bit toolset, which is I think the default for 32-bit configurations.  I join @MichaëlRoy advice.

Comment: `The code compiles successfully, but the executables generated do not work.` You have to make it work in 32-bits and then try to setup your project dependencies on x64 configuration. 
You have 2 hard tasks: migrating from old VS to VS19 and then making support for x64, don't try making it at once.

Comment: Also note that visual studio has distinct configuration sets for all four combinations of {release,debug} x {x86, x64}. You will need to copy a good chunk of the settings for 32bit builds to the 64bit configurations as well, making sure to substitute 64bit dependencies where needed.